# Upgrading webpack dependency

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, copy-webpack-plugin

I've upgraded dependencies in my application. In particular `webpack` from `4.43` to `5.88`, related dependencies are also updated:

Now, I see this error during `yarn build`.

```
    YN0000: [..]: Process started
    ➤ YN0000: [..]: Process started
    ➤ YN0000: [..]: Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
    ➤ YN0000: [..]:  - options[0] has an unknown property 'to'. These properties are valid:
    ➤ YN0000: [..]:    object { patterns, options? }
    ➤ YN0000: [..]:  - options[1] has an unknown property 'to'. These properties are valid:
    ➤ YN0000: [..]:    object { patterns, options? }
    ➤ YN0000: [..]: ValidationError: Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
```

and some following stack trace:

```
    ➤ YN0000: [..]:     at validate (%app%\node_modules\copy-webpack-plugin\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:158:11)
    ➤ YN0000: [..]:     at new CopyPlugin (%app%\node_modules\copy-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:172:5)
    ➤ YN0000: [..]:     at configure (%app%\innerproject\/webpack.config.babel.js:86:5)
    ➤ YN0000: [..]:     at _default (%app%\innerproject\/webpack.config.babel.js:131:31)
    ➤ YN0000: [..]:     at handleFunction (%app%\innerproject\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\prepareOptions.js:21:13)
    ➤ YN0000: [..]:     at prepareOptions (%app%\innerproject\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\prepareOptions.js:9:5)
    ➤ YN0000: [..]:     at requireConfig (%app%\innerproject\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:117:14)
    ➤ YN0000: [..]:     at %app%\innerproject\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:123:17
    ➤ YN0000: [..]:     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
...
```

This is what I have in webpack.config.babel.js (line 86):

```
plugins: [
..
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: 'src/data', to: 'data' },
    { from: 'src/images', to: 'images' }
  ]),
..
]
```

it looks like `to` argument is no longer supported, where can I find a new format?

UPDATE:

when I use a newer format:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin(
{
  patterns: [
    { from: 'src/data', to: 'data' },
    { from: 'src/images', to: 'images' }
]}),
```

I see a different error:

```
        YN0000: [..]: %app%\innerproject\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:281
        ➤ YN0000: [..]:                               throw err;
        ➤ YN0000: [..]:                               ^
        ➤ YN0000: [..]:
        ➤ YN0000: [..]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tap')
        ➤ YN0000: [..]:     at HtmlWebpackPlugin.apply (%app%\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\index.js:40:31)
        ➤ YN0000: [..]:     at webpack (%app%\innerproject\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:51:13)
        ➤ YN0000: [..]:     at processOptions (%app%\innerproject\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:272:16)
        ➤ YN0000: [..]:     at %app%\innerproject\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:364:3
```

`webpack cli` I use is `"webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the latest config example [on the NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin) or [on the README](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin#getting-started):

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin({
    patterns: [
        { from: 'src/data', to: 'data' },
        { from: 'src/images', to: 'images' }
    ],
}),
```

Comment: yeah, I've just found it too, but it gives different error, please see update in the main question

Comment: That error seems to come from html-webpack-plugin